# Python For loop with data (csv)

Tags: python

I have this data:

http://prntscr.com/gojey0

Which keeps going on downward.

How do I find the top 20 most common platforms using python code?

I'm really lost. I thought of maybe going through the list in a for loop and counting each one? that seems wrong though..

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/

something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file.csv")
top_platforms = df.nlargest(20, "Score")["Platform"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary would be a good choice for collecting this information:

Initialize an empty dict.

For each row in the csv file:

1. Get the platform column.
2. If that platform is not already in the dict, create it with a count of one.
3. Otherwise if it is already in the dict, increment its count by one.

When you're done, sort the dict by the count value and print the top 20 entries.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas to read in csv files

```
import pandas as pd
from collection import Counter
df = pd.read_csv('DATA.csv') # read the csv file into a dataframe *df*
# create counter object containing dictionary
# invoke the pandas groupby and count methods
d = Counter(dict(df.groupby(['Platform'])['Platform'].count()))
```

`d` will be a counter object "containing" a dictionary of the form `{<platform>:<number of counts in dataset>}`

You can get the top `k` most common platforms as follows:

```
k = 20
d.most_common(k)
>>> [('<platform1>', count1),
    ('<platform2>', count2),
    ('<platform3>', count3),
    ('<platform4>', count4),
    ....
```

Hope that helps. In future it would be better to see the head (first few lines) of your data or what code you have tried so far... or even what data wrangling tool you're using!